# MacBook Ambient Light Sensor Drivers for Windows

Tags: windows-7, drivers, macbook, boot-camp

Is there a way to enable the ambient light sensor on a MacBook Pro unibody while running Windows? I'm particularly interested in a compatible driver for use in Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no compatible ALS driver for Win 7 x64 yet. Many have asked, none have found so far.

Answer (score 1):

This might help :
[MacBook Tray Tools - Drivers for keyboard backlight and sensors of your MacBook / Pro](http://dmitri.v.googlepages.com/macbooktraytools).

Quote:

> What is it?
>
> If you happened to be a happy MacBook
>   / MacBook Pro owner running Windows
>   with Bootcamp, you surely felt annoyed
>   of current lack of driver support for
>   some neat features offered by this
>   beautiful piece of hardware. For
>   example the keyboard backlight and
>   automatic brightness adjustment based
>   on environment light is completely
>   lacking any drivers. How long would it
>   take for Apple to release the complete
>   set of drivers and how well the Apple
>   hardware will be supported under
>   Windows compared to Mac OS X, nobody
>   can say for sure. The recent release
>   of Bootcamp did not include this
>   support.
>
> I put together a small tray resident
>   application which lets you activate
>   and control the keyboard light, it
>   also accesses the light sensors to
>   resemble the automatic light
>   adjustment to the environment light as
>   you know it fromMac OS X.

Comment: I saw that, too. It was last updated over 3 years ago, which gives me pause.

Comment: Might still work, though.

Comment: If it was open source code then it might work. Unfortunately it has no chance of working because it has a dependency on inpout32.dll. The code would need to be reworked and liked to inpoutx64.dll to have a hope of working on Win7 x64. It is a good idea, though.

Comment: Can't you run it in compatibility mode?

Comment: Not possible. You can't use 32-bit drivers in 64-bit Windows.

Comment: In that case, caliban was right.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it under XP with SP3 and it choked my machine... I was barely able to stop the process.

Comment: Are you referring to the MacBook tray tools mentioned by "harrymc"?